# Require jQuery locally in Symfony3 with Bootstrap4 and webpack encore

Tags: jquery, symfony, bootstrap-4, webpack-encore

According to Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html#importing-bootstrap-javascript), Bootstrap expects jQuery to be available as a global variable. But in my application, jQuery is not used on every page, but only in a few pages that have jQuery-dependent components. I'd like to avoid adding jQuery globally, and add it in individual pages. Is it possible to require jQuery selectively, and if so, how?

Comment: The goal of encore is to define a root js file that require what you need, if you need jquery only inside few files then just require it on these files let $ = require('jquery')
But don't forget to include your js files into a root js that will be loaded by encore.

Comment: Thank you @jeremy. I added `let $ = require('jquery')` to a js file that was loaded by encore and added to the template, but the the jQuery-dependent Bootstrap components on the page (modals and collapsible sections) still don't work. I also tried `let jQuery = require('jquery')`, with no success. Adding `let $ = require('jquery')` in a js file lets me use jQuery code in that file, but it does not help with Bootstrap components.

Comment: this is absolutly not clear, you need bootstrap feature only on some views? If yes i think something is wrong

Comment: To be more specific, some of the pages in my application use modals and collapsible sections. These components don't work without jQuery. I'm trying to find a way to use modals and collapsible sections without requiring jQuery globally, but only requiring it selectively in those pages where modals and collapsible sections are present. Hopefully this makes it more clear. Thanks again for any input.

Comment: you can require with a path, the node_modules directory is known so you can ask for the js inside it and require jquery for example only for few pages

Comment: I tried `var $ = require('../../node_modules/jquery')` and `var jQuery = require('../../node_modules/jquery)`, but the modals still wouldn't work. I also tried the same statements with `require('../../node_modules/jquery/src/core')` with the same result.